# Spring boot JPA, entity with @EmbeddedId - findyById method is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to use the CrudRepository's findById method to get an object from the database by it's id. The id of the main entity is a composite key, utilized by an @Embeadable class including all the properties.

Here are the details of my current implementation:

Here is the main entity class (InitialMoneyCount):

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class InitialMoneyCount {
    @EmbeddedId
    @NonNull
    private InitialMoneyCountId initialMoneyCountId;
    @NonNull
    private BigDecimal amount;
    @NonNull
    private BigDecimal amountSystemCurrency;
    @NonNull
    private String currency;

    // Default constructor
    public InitialMoneyCount() {
    }

    // Constructor with all properties
    public InitialMoneyCount(InitialMoneyCountId initialMoneyCountId, BigDecimal amount,
                             BigDecimal amountSystemCurrency, String currency) {
        this.initialMoneyCountId = initialMoneyCountId;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.amountSystemCurrency = amountSystemCurrency;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    // Builder
    public static InitialMoneyCountBuilder builder() {
        return new InitialMoneyCountBuilder();
    }

    public static class InitialMoneyCountBuilder {
        private InitialMoneyCountId initialMoneyCountId;
        private BigDecimal amount;
        private BigDecimal amountSystemCurrency;
        private String currency;

        public InitialMoneyCountBuilder initialMoneyCountId(InitialMoneyCountId initialMoneyCountId) {
            this.initialMoneyCountId = initialMoneyCountId;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountBuilder amount(BigDecimal amount) {
            this.amount = amount;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountBuilder amountSystemCurrency(BigDecimal amountSystemCurrency) {
            this.amountSystemCurrency = amountSystemCurrency;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountBuilder currency(String currency) {
            this.currency = currency;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCount build() {
            return new InitialMoneyCount(initialMoneyCountId, amount, amountSystemCurrency, currency);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the primary key @Embeddable class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
@Getter
public class InitialMoneyCountId implements Serializable {
    @NonNull
    private UUID posTerminalId;
    @NonNull
    private UUID cashierId;
    @NonNull
    private UUID cashDrawerId;
    @NonNull
    private LocalDate bookingDate;
    @NonNull
    private Integer bookingPeriod;
    @NonNull
    private UUID paymentMethodId;

    // Default constructor
    public InitialMoneyCountId() {
    }

    // Constructor with all properties
    public InitialMoneyCountId(UUID posTerminalId, UUID cashierId, UUID cashDrawerId,
                               LocalDate bookingDate, Integer bookingPeriod, UUID paymentMethodId) {
        this.posTerminalId = posTerminalId;
        this.cashierId = cashierId;
        this.cashDrawerId = cashDrawerId;
        this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
        this.bookingPeriod = bookingPeriod;
        this.paymentMethodId = paymentMethodId;
    }

    // Builder
    public static InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder builder() {
        return new InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder();
    }

    public static class InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder {
        private UUID posTerminalId;
        private UUID cashierId;
        private UUID cashDrawerId;
        private LocalDate bookingDate;
        private Integer bookingPeriod;
        private UUID paymentMethodId;

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder posTerminalId(UUID posTerminalId) {
            this.posTerminalId = posTerminalId;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder cashierId(UUID cashierId) {
            this.cashierId = cashierId;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder cashDrawerId(UUID cashDrawerId) {
            this.cashDrawerId = cashDrawerId;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder bookingDate(LocalDate bookingDate) {
            this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder bookingPeriod(Integer bookingPeriod) {
            this.bookingPeriod = bookingPeriod;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountIdBuilder paymentMethodId(UUID paymentMethodId) {
            this.paymentMethodId = paymentMethodId;
            return this;
        }

        public InitialMoneyCountId build() {
            return new InitialMoneyCountId(posTerminalId, cashierId, cashDrawerId,
                    bookingDate, bookingPeriod, paymentMethodId);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the JpaRepository interface definition:

```
@Repository
public interface InitialMoneyCountRepository extends JpaRepository<InitialMoneyCount, InitialMoneyCountId> {}
```

And here is a test for findById(InitialMoneyCountId id):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT, properties = "spring.h2.console.enabled=true")
public class InitialMoneyCountRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    SampleDataGenerator sampleDataGenerator;
    @Autowired
    InitialMoneyCountRepository initialMoneyCountRepository;

    @AfterEach
    public void resetDatabase_AfterEach() {
        initialMoneyCountRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @After
    public void resetDatabase_After() {
        initialMoneyCountRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Before
    public void resetDatabase_Before() {
        initialMoneyCountRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void findById_sucess() {
        InitialMoneyCountId initialMoneyCountId = InitialMoneyCountId.builder()
                .posTerminalId(UUID.randomUUID())
                .cashDrawerId(UUID.randomUUID())
                .cashierId(UUID.randomUUID())
                .bookingDate(LocalDate.now())
                .bookingPeriod(5)
                .paymentMethodId(UUID.randomUUID())
                .build();
        InitialMoneyCount initialMoneyCount = InitialMoneyCount.builder()
                .initialMoneyCountId(initialMoneyCountId)
                .amount(BigDecimal.valueOf(555.55))
                .amountSystemCurrency(BigDecimal.valueOf(55.555))
                .currency(Currency.EUR.value())
                .build();
        InitialMoneyCount savedInitialMoneyCount = initialMoneyCountRepository.save(initialMoneyCount);
        Optional<InitialMoneyCount> imc = initialMoneyCountRepository.findById(initialMoneyCountId);
        Assertions.assertTrue(imc.isPresent());
    }
}
```

However I am not able to find the object by it's id. This is the exception I am getting:

```
expected: <true> but was: <false>
Comparison Failure: 
Expected :true
Actual   :false
<Click to see difference>

org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from initial_money_count where booking_date=? and booking_period=? and cash_drawer_id=? and cashier_id=? and payment_method_id=? and pos_terminal_id=?; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: delete from initial_money_count where booking_date=? and booking_period=? and cash_drawer_id=? and cashier_id=? and payment_method_id=? and pos_terminal_id=?
```

Any ideas of what I am missing here?

I suppose that CrudRepository's findById method works for @Embeadable composite Ids, correct?

Comment: could you implement the equals and hashcode for the embedded id and your main entity and try again ?

Comment: also I advice you to use Lombok to reduce the amount of boiler plate code you did to create a builder

Comment: Thanks mr.Penguin for your comments, I have tried it but it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Annotating my Test class as @Transactional seem to do the work though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I could not reproduce the issue with spring-boot:3/jakarta.perstistence(,hibernate:6),

switching to spring-boot:2/javax.persistence immediately *hit*!

(Quick) Solution:

```java
@Test
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional // !
```

...(tracing) sql and params seemed correct, so the problem must be somewhere in transaction propagation/flushing.

Reasons:
(Well hidden) in the release notes/version diff between spring-boot 2 and 3/ hibernate 5 vs 6... spring(-boot)-test(!)...

Comment: Indeed, adding the @Transactional annotation seem to solve the issue